# I installed anaconda 3 with python version 3.10.9. I tried opening jupyter notebook but the ff results were displayed

Tags: anaconda3

thesis) C:\Users\Lenovo>jupyter notebook
usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir] [--paths] [--json] [--debug] [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
subcommand     the subcommand to launch

options:
-h, --help     show this help message and exit
--version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
--config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
--data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
--runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
--paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable format.
--json         output paths as machine-readable json
--debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands: dejavu execute kernel kernelspec migrate nbconvert qtconsole run script troubleshoot trust

Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.

I am still trouble shooting for solution because I installed jupyter using the command: conda install -c anaconda jupyter in the new environment I created for my work (thesis)